# do skylake core i5 CPUs support hyper-threading technology?

Tags: cpu, intel-core-i5, hyper-threading

Do the skylake core i5 series of desktop CPUs support hyper-threading technology?

Comment: What research have you done so far? What does that tell you?

Comment: You haven't specified whether you are talking about mobile or desktop processors. Some of the mobile ones do but the desktop ones don't. This is easily researched on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Core_i5_microprocessors

Comment: oh sorry i meant desktop processors

Comment: core i5 6600k. it seems that it doesn't

Comment: technically, based on the architecture it does but it is disabled on the silicon level, because of binning and financial sense.

Comment: so is there a way to enable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following information, with regard to Intel Hyper-Threading Technology, applies to all Skylake i5 processors.

[image]

Comment: @jellyfishman What's confusing? You say Wikipedia tells you they don't, as does this answer (which has a screenshot taken directly from Intel).

Comment: oh sorry i didnt understand correctly, now i understand